# NullPointerException in setAdapter method of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

My code is working properly, but i am worried about the warning given by android studio during inspection of the code in the line next to the comment(//next line) in the following activity code. It says that it may produce null pointer exception. I am not able to figure out the reason behind it. I went through some other answers related to same issue but could not find the exact reason. Here is the snapshot of the message by android studio.

[image]
Activity Code

```
package com.example.kedee.mistu.services;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.kedee.mistu.R;

public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] catNames= {"A","E","T","E","S","F","M","P","S","E","C","H","M","Others"};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_listView);
        //next line
        listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,catNames));
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
}
```

Layout Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.kedee.mistu.services.Test">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/test_listView"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"
        >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am no sure but you can try below code

```
if(listView!=null)
{
     listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,catNames));
       listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
}
```

try to use

```
ActivityName.this or getApplicationContext()
```

Comment: Yeah, tried that but still getting the same message.. :/

Comment: Yup, this worked :) but how could list view ever be null ?

Comment: if user not define, it generally happens to new developer!

Comment: Ohh..okee :) Thanks a lot bhai :)

Comment: @SumitSagar: No Problem! Any time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106086/discussion-between-nirav-ranpara-and-sumit-sagar).